# Executar função javascript com a aba do navegador fechada

Tags: javascript

Sou nova por aqui gostaria de saber como faço pra executar a função abaixo mesmo se o visitante pular pra outra aba do navegador (mais mantendo a aba do script aberta em outra aba).

O script abaixo funciona, mais só funciona se o visitante do site estiver visualizando a pagina, caso ele pule pra outra aba do navegador o script para de funcionar e só volta a funcionar caso ele volte pra aba do script.

```
<script>
      window.setInterval(function() {
        showlocation();
      }, 200000);  // 2000==2 seconds

      function showlocation() {
        navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(callback);
      }

      function callback(position) {
        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var lon = position.coords.longitude;
        document.getElementById('latitude').innerHTML = lat;
        document.getElementById('longitude').innerHTML = lon;
        $.post('mapa3_post.php', 'lat=' + lat + '&lon=' + lon, function(response) {
          //alert(response);
        });
      }
</script>
```

Comment: `200000` não é dois segundos, também fiquei sem entender !

Comment: rsrs pode esquecer esse detalhe , foi eu eu fazendo testes... sabe me dizer como faço pra chamar a função mesmo com a aba fechada?

Comment: O browser não garante a execução dos timers com a aba fora de foco. Mas o timer é redundante, você já está rodando o callback de tempos em tempos – teoricamente, toda vez que a posição do dispositivo muda.

Comment: obrigado bfvaretto , estou usando isso para salvar a localização do usuário no BD mysql , o problema é que só salva se a aba tiver em foco ... tem alguma sugestão?

Comment: Leia isto, https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/background_tabs, os browsers não apoiam o uso funções em background tabs, talvez a sua aplicação precise focar no público mobile somente.

Comment: ruansenadev é possível enviar a função com a aba do navegador do CELULAR/TABLETE fora de foco? se sim como ficaria o código?